# How many daily/encounter powers can I "prepare" per day?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

The book is a little confusing on this.   Especially for classes with spellbooks.

Is it (in laymans terms):
One power, per level (minus your level one at wills?), per day?

If so, how does a spellbook help?
Two powers, per level (minus level 1 at will's), per day?

Answer (score 7):

**Each class can be different.**

All of the original classes in the *Player's Handbook* use the same chart, found on page 29.  There are several levels where no power is gained (4th, 8th, etc).

The Essentials classes can be quite different, you have to consult each class to determine when your character gains new powers.

Spellbooks are a bit different, they are detailed on page 158 of the Player's Handbook.  After an extended rest, the character prepares the number of daily and utility spells required for their class.  When the character gains a new level that has a daily or utility power two new spells are selected for the spellbook, however only one can be prepared after each extended rest.

Answer (score 1):

To put this into plain english:

You get all the powers your current class and level entitles you to.

If your class uses a spellbook, your daily and utility powers are picked after an extended rest, picking from the spellbook, which contains twice as many as you can prepare.

you still have the usual number of powers, you just have more flexibility, being able to pick from two every day for each daily, as opposed to normal classes picking once per level.